# grunt does not compile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less

I work with Bootstrap and I have this problem.

I have installed Grunt and compile only `style.less` but not the other files.

When I change something in file which is import to `style.less` it works only when I reeboot Grunt.

What could be wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Below is my `Gruntfile.js`.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/style.less"
        }
      }
    }, watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['less/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);
};
```

My theme folder:

```
--bootstrap
--config
--css
   -style.css
--fonts
--less
    - component
    - jquery-ui
    bootstrap.less
    overrides.less
    style.less
    variable-overrides.less
--node_modules
--templates
gruntfile.js
mytheme.info.yml
mytheme.libraries.yml
mytheme.theme
package.json
package-lock.json
services.yml
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post your project folder structure?

Comment: I added structure below.

Comment: you should remove the answer, and add the structure to your question.

Comment: @muecas our all comments just disappeared. In last message I said that I have no problem with compiling style.less. Changes in style.less are ok. Only variable-overrides.less it needs grunt restart.